# Updating worklight via instalation manager doesn't do anything

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I've downloaded a new fixpack for worklight and I've added that as a repository for the IBM Installation Manager and disabled the checkbox that checks for updates.

Then in IBM IM I try to update and the new fixpack displays correctly, the problem arises when select the Update Package and press next.

After that nothing happens, the IBM IM displays grayed out buttons on back, next, update and cancel.

Edit:

I've when looking for my IM logs and found out that on all the attempts I've had, the IM gets stuck on the same phase.

```
<entry num='68' time='1416502265029' elapsed='00:31.60' level='INFO' thread='ModalContext' startNum='52'>
 <logger>com.ibm.cic.agent.internal.core.Director</logger>
 <method>prepare</method>
 <message>
   <key>Elapsed time {0} for: {1}</key>
   <arg>00:00.05</arg>
   <arg>Preparing com.ibm.imp 6.2.0.20140613_0756</arg>
 </message>
 </entry>
</log>
```

I've even tried to reinstall the IM like it's described here.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSDV2W_1.5.0/com.ibm.silentinstall12.doc/topics/t_silent_installIM_IMinst.html

Still no luck and I get stuck on the same step.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Edit2:

Could it be heap exhaustion? I don't have much RAM on this machine and WL Server is running...

Comment: You have to stop all WebSphere/Worklight java processes, otherwise update will fail due to files being locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question lies within the console mode on the IBM Installation Manager.

I went to /tools and fired up the imcl binary. If I updated the Worklight Server with the console mode I get the following error:

> Reason: The package IBM Worklight Server 6.2.0 does not support being installed in console mode.

At this time I was getting a little frustaed, but then I run again the command with some new parameters

```
./imcl -showVerboseProgress updateAll
```

This time I got a new error that the GUI interface never showed me.

```
Preparing IBMÂ® Worklight Server Complete for eclipse
Preparing IBMÂ® Worklight Server
ERROR: The following errors were generated while updating.
ERROR:   Database APPCNTR (URL jdbc:db2://<someip>:<somePort>/APPCNTR) is not accessible
```

And this is something I can work with. :)

In fact, I've solved this issue and was able to update my worklight.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the repository of the base release into IBM Installation Manager as well.
See 'Information about repositories' at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_prep_become_familiar_with_IBM_IM.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't found out where I should download the repository for the IBM IM. But please check out my update on the main question as I've found out additional information. Unfortunately I still can't do much with that.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom sounds like IBM Installation Manager (IM) has encountered an exception. When this happens, you find the log file here:

For a system-wide IM:

- On Unix: /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs/
- On Windows: C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\logs\

For a per-user IM:

- On Unix: $HOME/var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs/
- On Windows: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\IBM\Installation Manager\logs\

Comment: I've edited my post to add some follow up information regarding logs and some troubleshooting.